# Firebase Custom Auth - What/Where metrics are available?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, metrics

I use Firebase Custom Auth JWT.

Is there a place (in the Console) or a method (CLI?) by which I can gather the metrics behind the Custom Auth JWT usage?

For instance, I need data like,
How many devices authenticated using the Token?
What timeframews were these device authentication at?
How long were each device session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such reporting built into Firebase Authentication.

You'd typically [fire an Analytics event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events) when signing the user in from the front-end. When you're using a custom authentication token, you could integrate some form of analytics into the minting process, or also use Firebase's Analytics integration with Google Analytics in the front-end when it uses the token.